# jQuery remove class from duplicate item

Tags: jquery, html

I have a jQuery work around to allow links to activate their sub menu on a mobile device without navigating to the clicked link till the second click.

```
jQuery('ul.nav > li.parent > a').click(function(event){
  if (jQuery(this).parent().hasClass('firstClick')) {
  } 
  else {
    event.preventDefault();
    jQuery(this).parent().addClass('firstClick')
  }
});
```

I would like it so when I `addClass('firstClick')` in the else, it will also find all other list items with the class of 'firstClick' and remove it.
I tried adding in

```
find('ul.nav > li.firstClick').removeClass('firstClick');
```

to the else, but to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks.

Comment: have you tried siblings().removeClass('firstClick')?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jQuery('ul.nav > li.parent > a').click(function (event) {
    var $li = jQuery(this).parent()
    if (!$li.hasClass('firstClick')) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $li.addClass('firstClick')
        $li.siblings('.firstClick').removeClass('firstClick')
    }
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't your parent variable be jQuery(this).parent() if you're calling it in later?

Comment: @AndyHolmes no since jQuery methods does chaining `jQuery(this).parent()` and `jQuery(this).parent().addClass('firstClick')` will return the same value

Comment: why was this down voted? it was just what i was looking for, and i was unaware of the chaining so thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
jQuery('ul.nav > li.parent > a').click(function(event){
  if (jQuery(this).parent().hasClass('firstClick')) {
  } 
  else {
    event.preventDefault();
    jQuery('.firstClick').removeClass('firstClick'); //remove class
    jQuery(this).parent().addClass('firstClick');
  }
});
```

Comment: not too sure why it was down voted, this answer does the job just fine.